# Regex for EML Base64 block

Tags: regex, base64, eml

Is it possible to use regex to match **entire** RFC1341 / RFC2045 Base64 blocks (up to 76 characters per line), **not** just individual lines?

The closest that I've managed to get is `^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9+\/=-]{1,76}[\r|\n|\r\n]?)+` but it only finds individual lines in Notepad++ and it selects stuff other than Base64 blocks too.

Examples:

- EML file: https://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/14672.html
- Regex: https://regex101.com/r/JTh5uZ/1

Is this possible?

Comment: Try this regex: `^(?:[\w+/=-]{76}\R)+[\w+/=-]{1,76}`

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Thanks! Want to post as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex to grab all `eml` blocks:

```sh
^(?:[\w+/=-]{76}\R)+[\w+/=-]{1,76}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jQok16/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Line start
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `[\w+/=-]{76}`: Match 76 of allowed characters inside `[...]`
  - `\R`: Match line break of any kind (unicode)
- `)+`: end non-capture group. Match 1 or more of this group.
- `[\w+/=-]{1,76}`: Match 1 to 76 of allowed characters inside `[...]`